# What would cause a residual plot to be entirely above 0?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, data-visualization

What would cause a regression model to always under predict?

For over a year now an associate of mine has been producing a linear model for a client which predicts trends with reasonable accuracy but always under predicts the magnitude.

This has bothered me for a while and each time I see it or get reminded of it I attempt to find the cause and turn up short.

EDIT: Reading through the comments I realized that I misspoke. Rather than the residuals 'always' being biased the aggregation of the model is always under the actual. I'm not sure how to gracefully recover except to blame coffee/sleep etc. What I wanted to ask is closer to this, for each month the sum of the actual results is greater than the predicted results 'every' time.

Comment: What kind of regression method did he use? Was it a voluntary decision to underestimate for some reason or did it just so happen?

Comment: Also (and see my comment on the first answer posted): are you referring to predictions of future values based on past data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To summarize the various comments and answers so far:

1. If the predictions are on data that was not part of  the training sample, there could be a systematic difference between the training data and the prediction data. For example, if you are fitting time-series data and the data contains an upward-curving trend, then predicting the future from the past with a linear model will yield under-predictions on average.
2. If the model always under-predicts on training data (or even just on average), it could be a less commonly used variety of linear model, such as a quantile regression model; or it might not contain an intercept (or terms which can linearly combine to form an intercept).
3. If the model is standard linear least squares and does contain an intercept or equivalent spanning terms, then Benjamin's post is correct. The phenomenon you observed cannot possibly happen. So there must be an error in the computational code used for the model's training or prediction.

Comment: Reading through the comments I realized that I misspoke. Rather than the residuals 'always' being biased the aggregation of the model is always under the actual. I'm not sure how to gracefully recover except to blame coffee/sleep etc. What I wanted to ask is closer to this, for each month the sum of the actual results is greater than the predicted results 'every' time.

Comment: My answer applies equally well if the model is only underpredicting on average.

Comment: I believe he's forced a zero intercept. I'll have to research more, I was under the impression that this would simply cause a different pattern. But in hind-hind sight I realize that I was again thinking of residuals.

Answer (score 4):

We will assume that the linear regression fit is through least squares, contains an intercept, and the residual plot is that from the training data.

From the normal equations, we see that the residuals of the regression has sample mean 0. Therefore, it's not possible for the residual plot to be entirely above 0. There must be a mistake somewhere in the visualization/computation.

Comment: You assume the model is linear, that it contains a constant term, and that it involves a symmetric loss.  Perhaps one or more of these is not the case--but that would not imply there's a mistake.  For instance, it could be a quantile regression targeted at a low quantile.

Comment: Thanks! I neglected to comment that the model need an intercept. You're also right that I'm assuming that he's using a standard linear regression--I thought this was a safe assumption though, since the question mentions that the OP is using a "linear regression model"

Comment: Yet another assumption is that the model is being used on the data on which it was based. It seems quite possible to me that the OP is referring to out-of-sample predictions, e.g that a model fitted for 1984-2014 is being used to predict 2015, 2016, etc. In that case "because the future is not like the past" is quite possibly the only principle to invoke.

Comment: Benjamin, you're right that the OP said "linear," but we should be a little cautious about what that really says, because although statisticians are agreed what "linear model" means, people in general are not.  When trying to explain descriptions of strange behavior, it's usually a good idea to look for misunderstandings in terminology before assuming some kind of error has been made.